# Passing value from Django view to AngularJS inserted template

Tags: html, angularjs, django, django-templates

Is there a way to pass a value from a Django view to an AngularJS inserted template?

In my view.py I have the code:

```js
count_users = Profile.objects.filter(user_id__gte = 0).count()
context_dict = {'users': count_users}
return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context_dict)
```

In dashboard.html I am able to insert the user count into the html as follows:

```js
{{ users }}
```

This works fine but dashboard.html uses AngularJS to insert some more html as follows:

```html
<div ui-view class="fade-in-up">
</div>
```

Mt problem that the html file inserted by AngularJS does not respond to the:

```js
{{ users }}
```

Is there a way to pass the value of users through to the AngularJS inserted HTML?

Comment: The users variable has to be attached to the $scope, otherwise it will not appear in such a binding.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by attached to the $scope? I don't know what that is. How would I do that?

Comment: In angular you have a variable that is called $scope. If you do `$scope.someVar = 5` and then `{{ someVar }}`, it will appear. If you do just `var someVar = 5` and then try to bind it the same way - it will not work. So to display the variable you want properly, you must use javascript and attach it to the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using ng-init you can attach your value into the $scope

```
<div ui-view class="fade-in-up" ng-init="User='{{user}}' " >

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect

Comment: Can you share your Django and AngularJS code? This solution is not working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript do:

```
mainModule
    .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```

This way, if you want to bind an angular variable in the html, you use:

```
{$ variable $}
```

If you want to add a Django variable, you use:

```
 {{ variable }}
```

And your code may work if you leave it as it is, and just add this configuration to the angular module.